# Create java test on RobotFramework without run it

Tags: java, robotframework

My scenario is: I have a simulator that only accepts java tests.
My idea to implement keyword-driven is to use a tool only to "translate" my table test to a java file that then I can run  it in my simulator.
Do you think is possible? there is another tool suitable for this? At first look I was thinking on RobotFramework. But I only can run the tests in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jython to call Python or Java classes. Then you call RobotFramework tests with `jybot`.